PyArg_ParseTuple depends on order of pointer-declarations
I am using the Charm-Crypto library for Python and encountered a segmentation fault due to gobj being parsed as a null-pointer in this function of the c-implementation of the library:
static PyObject *ECE_hash(ECElement *self, PyObject *args) {

    char *msg = NULL;
    int msg_len;
    GroupType type;
    ECElement *hashObj = NULL;
    ECGroup *gobj = NULL;
    
    if(PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "Os#i", &gobj, &msg, &msg_len, &type)) {
            VERIFY_GROUP(gobj); 
            ...
    }
    ...
}

The python-code calling the function is as follows:
from charm.core.math.elliptic_curve import elliptic_curve,ZR,hashEC
from charm.toolbox.eccurve import secp256k1
curve = elliptic_curve(nid=secp256k1)
hashVal = hashEC(curve, b'A', ZR)
print("hashVal:", hashVal)

When I tried to replicate the behavior in other functions in which gobj got parsed correctly I "fixed" it by changing the order of the pointer-declarations:
static PyObject *ECE_hash(ECElement *self, PyObject *args) {

    ECElement *hashObj = NULL;
    GroupType type;
    ECGroup *gobj = NULL;
    char *msg = NULL;
    int msg_len;

    if(PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "Os#i", &gobj, &msg, &msg_len, &type)) {
            VERIFY_GROUP(gobj); 
            ...
    }
    ...
}

Everytime type is declared before msg_len gobj gets parsed correctly.
Is there an explanation for this behavior and it is intended or is there some deeper lying problem that I am overlooking?

s# needs a Py_ssize_t, not an int.

This project looks pretty close to dead. Build status unknown, website link is dead, most recent tag is from 2013, issues are mostly getting ignored... commits are still happening, but barely.

Thank you! That solved it! - I use it primarily to learn and plan to switch to something better soon.

The issue you are encountering seems to be related to how the PyArg_ParseTuple function interprets the format string and associated variables. PyArg_ParseTuple is a function in the Python API that converts Python function arguments into C variables. It uses a format string to determine the type and order of arguments it should interpret. According to the Python 3 documentation, if the format string does not exactly match the types and order of the variables provided, this can result in errors like the one you are facing. Therefore, it is crucial to check if the format string you are using in PyArg_ParseTuple is correct and compatible with the types and sequence of the variables you are passing. Ensuring this match helps avoid misinterpretation issues and execution failures in the code.
